# Apache ProxyPass preserve port

Tags: apache

I have a problem configuring the reverse proxy within apache, in a way the port defined in forwarding is passed to the destination page.

The landing page I have no control over it, and it in some places mounts https links using port forwarding

if I define the forwarding that way it mounts the links on the page http://127.0.0.1:8087/xyz

```
ProxyPass         / http://127.0.0.1:8087
ProxyPassReverse  / http://127.0.0.1:8087
```

if I set forwarding that way it mounts the links on the page http://example.com:8087/xyz

changing port 80 for forwarding port 8087, I need to keep the same source port 80 and 443

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass         / http://127.0.0.1:8087
ProxyPassReverse  / http://127.0.0.1:8087
```

I tried some parameters but without success

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
RequestHeader set X_SERVER_PORT 443
```

I need to forward the source port for forwarding, just like ProxyPreserveHost does with the name